# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dataTransfer')

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code for getting files dragged and dropped into an area:

```js
//track drop
document.getElementById("track-drop").addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add("drag-enter");

  console.log("Event: dragenter")
});

document.getElementById("track-drop").addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log("Event: dragover")
});

document.getElementById("track-drop").addEventListener("dragleave", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.remove("drag-enter");

  console.log("Event: dragleave")
});

document.getElementById("track-drop").addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.remove("drag-enter");

  console.log("Event: drop")

  var dropEvent = e.originalEvent;

  for (var i = 0; i < dropEvent.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
    console.log("New file: ", dropEvent.dataTransfer.files[i]);
  }
});
```

```css
.track-drop {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.track-drop::before {
  content: "Drop file(s) here!";
}

.track-drop.drag-enter {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="track-drop" id="track-drop"></div>
```

The problem is an error is received:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dataTransfer')

At this JS statement: `dropEvent.dataTransfer.files.length`

## Debugger

In my code, the debugger indicates `e.originalEvent` doesn't exist. But `e.dataTransfer` exists. I don't understand why.

[image: Breakpoint]

[image: Debugger watcher]

## Note

The same code works good at another web page. Surprisingly, `e.originalEvent` exists there. But `e.dataTransfer` doesn't.

[image: Good web page]

## Question

I don't understand why the code works for another web page and *not* mine. Did I miss a dependency or something?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? `e.originalEvent` isn't supported natively (obviously).

Comment: @code Let me use jQuery and see if it works...

Comment: I just saw that in your Note section...

Comment: @code In the code snippet in  the post, I just used jQuery dependency. But the error is still thrown!

Comment: Instead of `var dropEvent = e.originalEvent`, change it to just `var dropEvent = e.originalEvent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think  your error will solve by reading dataTransfer from event directly like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
  console.log("New file: ", e.dataTransfer.files[i]);
}
```

Comment: That's right, but I don't understand why the other web page works. But *not* mine?

Comment: I don't know you are using another library or not, but general way by pure js is the same reading files from `event.dataTransfer`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was facing something similar.
Changing e for event fixed it for me

```
  var dropEvent = event.originalEvent;

  for (var i = 0; i < dropEvent.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
    console.log("New file: ", dropEvent.dataTransfer.files[i]);
  }
```